# ng-model binding returning undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set a controller object property to an input text that the user enters using ng-model. Although when i log the value using console it returns as undefined, can anyone point out what i might be doing wrong?

Here is my HTML code

```
<ion-view view-title="Create Goal">
    <ion-content>
        <form style="margin-top:25px">

<!--Add the input text for the goal's name-->
            <div class="content double-padding" style="padding-bottom:0px">
                <h4 class="positive">{{ "_goal_name" | translate }}</h4>
                <input type="text" ng-model="name" style="border-bottom:1px solid grey;font-size:20px;margin-left:0px;width:100%">
            </div>



<!--Add the input range for the goal's distance-->
            <div class="content double-padding" style="padding-bottom:0px">
                <h4 class="positive">{{ "_goal_distance" | translate }}</h4>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="distance" style="border-bottom:1px solid grey;font-size:20px;margin-left:0px;width:100%">
            </div>



<!--Add the input text for the goal's start date in the form of aaaa-mm-dd-->
            <div class="content double-padding" style="padding-bottom:0px">
                <h4 class="positive">{{ "_goal_startDate" | translate }}</h4>
                <input type="text" ng-model="startDate" style="border-bottom:1px solid grey;font-size:20px;margin-left:0px;width:100%">
            </div>



<!--Add the input text for the goal's finish date in the form of aaaa-mm-dd-->
<!--Only appears  if the recurring option is true-->
            <div ng-show="goals.recurrent" class="content double-padding" style="padding-bottom:0px">
                <h4 class="positive">{{ "_goal_finishDate" | translate }}</h4>
                <input type="text" name="finishDate" style="border-bottom:1px solid grey;font-size:20px;margin-left:0px;width:100%">
            </div>



<!--Add the input checkbox for the goal's recurrence option -->
            <!--<ion-toggle ng-model="goals.recurrent" ng-checked="goalRecurrent" toggle-class="toggle-positive">-->
                <!--<h4 class="positive" style="font-size:18px;">{{ "_goal_recurrence" | translate }}</h4>-->
            <!--</ion-toggle>-->



<!--Add the button that calls the function to save the new goal-->
            <div class="content double-padding" style="padding-bottom:0px">
                <button ng-click="createGoal()" class="button  button-positive button-block">{{ "_button_create" | translate }}</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here is my Controller code

```
.controller("GoalFormCtrl", function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

    $scope.createGoal = function() {
        $scope.goal = {
            name : $scope.name,
            distance : $scope.distance,
            startDate : $scope.startDate,
            // recurrent : $scope.goalRecurrent
        };

        console.log($scope.goal);
    };
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

please check the below link, I have added this in a plunker

```
ng-controller="GoalFormCtrl"
```

model value is not getting the controller context

http://plnkr.co/edit/81Vi92bQjjhQxsIw1axD